# How will Google Search handle multiple Rich Snippet entries

Tags: rich-snippets, microdata, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

**Background**

- I've started to use Article markup (https://schema.org/Article) on a WordPress website. The aim is to add as much as possible properties.
- By using a (popular) plugin, basic Article data is parsed as JSON-LD which Google Rich Results Test is marking as eligible.
- I feel that the plugin does not cover enough properties, so I started to add additional properties using (mainly) microdata.
- By disabling the plugin I lose other functionality, which I feel is not worth adding manually.

Without spending too much time on this (traditional question being: is it worth it), I have the following problems and questions:

**Problems**

By using this approach, I'm getting two sets of Article entries in the Google Rich Results Test (one for each of the syntax)

To, maybe, be able to answer better:

- The IDs of the two entries are different (is that maybe the reason for the two entries? - Edit: I've matched the ID's but two entries are still created)
- Other properties (e.g. the updated date) in the microdata might be different
- There will be additional properties in the microdata

**Question**

Will Google use the first entry, the second entry (i.e. latest variables) or a combination of the two entries?

**Possible outcomes**

- Fix the problem
- Continue with two entries based on how Google handles the entries
- Remove the microdata altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same syntax, then you can merge entities via id. But Google does not merge them between mixed syntaxes.

If there are multiple entries for the same entity, I have tended to see Google pick one and ignore the others.

Sounds like your solution is to change your customisations to json-ld and include the same id as generated by the plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Figured a way to add additional markup using JSON-LD and PHP functions. Can now turn it into my own plugin. As you said, by keeping the IDs the same, Google reads them as one entry.